# Concatenating with Case Statement

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to concatenate Column C and Column H into Column F where it meets certain conditions.  I want to concatenate Column C where it equals "FS_Tier_1" with Column H where it equals "FS_CAP_1_001" into Column F (below the first line "FS_Tier_1"), until Column H reaches "FS_CAP_1_002".

This is what my data looks like:

[image]

I've searched a lot of vba code but cannot find something that quite fits what I'm trying to accomplish.  I mainly work in SQL Server, so I'm new to vba.  I've tried to use the WHERE clause but haven't been able to make it work.

```
Sub Concat_ParentCode_Cap1()

With Worksheets("PD Code Structure")

Dim ParentCode As Range
Dim TierCode As String
Dim CapCode As String

TierCode = "FS_Tier_1"
CapCode = "FS_CAP_1_001"
ParentCode = Range("F2:F24")

    Select Case CapCode
        Case "FS_CAP_1_001"
            ParentCode = TierCode & " . " & CapCode



    End Select
End With
End Sub
```

I keep getting the error message: "Object variable or with block variable not set."

I'd like my data to look like the following:

[image]

Comment: Which line gives the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `Set` the range:

`Set ParentCode = Range("F2:F24")`.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I can't believe it was that simple!!  :)

Comment: I'm trying to add another criteria to the case statement; however, I keep getting the error "Type Mistmatch."   My code is: `Sub Concat_ParentCode_Cap1_001()

With Worksheets("PD Code Structure")

Dim ParentCode As Range
Dim TierCode As String
Dim CapCode As String

CapCode = "FS_CAP_1_001"
TierCode = "FS_Tier_1"
Set ParentCode = Range("F3:F24")


    Select Case CapCode
        Case CapCode = "FS_CAP_1_001" And Range("E2:E1006").Value = 2
            ParentCode = TierCode & "." & CapCode
            
    End Select
End With
End Sub`

Comment: You compare an entire range with one number in `Range("E2:E1006").value = 2`. This is not possible.